# Is there a way to countinue to run the same bat file in command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a `.bat` script from the Command Prompt. However, once the script ends I want to either run the bat script again automatically or go back to the path and just manually enter the bat script name, and just run it again. Either one of those would be good.

I tried using pause or just using exit but it didn't work.

Batch Script:

```
@echo off
title runner
set /p man=
if %man% == 1 goto Kane

:1
echo Hello Kane
pause
exit
```

Comment: Instead of using `exit`, what about using `goto top`, and placing the label `:top` at the point you're wanting to return to?

Comment: FYI Up/down arrow in command prompt will navigate your previously entered commands, which can save some retyping.

Comment: I'm sure `pause` and `exit` *did work*; why should one expect them to establish a loop, which they are not intended for?

Comment: I wonder, why you don't complain about an error like `The system cannot find the batch label specified - Kane`... // Instead of `pause` or `Exit`, take a look to the [GOTO](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) command

Comment: @Stephan Yeah it was fixed in my code but when I copied and paste to stack overflow, I messed it up. Thanks though for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

### Academic Answer

It is possible to have cmd replace itself in a sense when launching another cmd script.

```
"%~0" %*
```

This will invoke itself and not return.
*(Merely using `%*` will not work correctly in any of the command-line arguments passed to this script needed quoting or escapes. You'd have to construct your own loop to handle that, if needed.)*

#### Example

```
@ECHO OFF

@ECHO Start: %LOOP_COUNT%
SET /A LOOP_COUNT=LOOP_COUNT+1
IF "%LOOP_COUNT%" GEQ "5" (
   @ECHO Finished.
   EXIT /B
)

@ECHO Looping: %LOOP_COUNT%
"%~0"

@ECHO THIS SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN
```

This script will invoke itself, incrementing `LOOP_COUNT` every time, until it reaches 6. Then it will quit.
Notice that the last line of the script will never execute because the running script is "replaced" (IDK the cmd parlance for this concept).

Note: If you wouldn't want to replace the script (which is *almost always* what I want), you'd use `CALL "%~0"` to invoke it, rather than just invoking it directly (i.e. `"%~0"`).

When I run the above script (I called it loop.cmd), I get:

```
c:\work\nsa_eavesdropping\scripts>loop.cmd
Start: 
Looping: 1
Start: 1
Looping: 2
Start: 2
Looping: 3
Start: 3
Looping: 4
Start: 4
Finished.
```

#### EXIT [/B]

It's usually preferable to use the `/B` parameter for `EXIT` so that the only the script execution is exited, not the calling shell process. There could be occasions for immediately killing the calling shell process, but most of the time, `EXIT /B` is the behavior I want.

### Why an infinite loop??

That being said, it may be that there's a better way to solve the problem than an infinite loop.